# How do I retrieve the reference number of an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to print something like this once I have my array finished:

Leg_______Departure Time_______Origin_____Destination________Travel Time

1..................(time).............................(place).........(place)........................(time)

2..................(time).............................(place).........(place)........................(time)

3..................(time).............................(place).........(place)........................(time)

I want to print out the array with automatically assigned numeric values based on the order that the user inputs the array item. I have a good idea on how to print out the array objects (time, places) but I do not know how to print out the reference number that would correspond. How would I go about making these numbers? (the dots are just placeholders and shouldnt appear in code. Id like to just float it in columns. SO doesnt let me place empty paces)

I thought I could ask the user for a location and track that item to a reference and add that reference to the the array, but that makes the numeric order static and I want them in order. Any help would be well appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet for better understanding

Comment: The term you are looking for is not 'reference number', it is 'index'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've provided, a simple implementation is:

```
List <FlightDetails> flightDetails = new ArrayList<>();

for (FlightDetails aflightDetail : flightDetails) {   
    System.out.println(aflightDetail.getDepartureTime() + " " +            
    aflightDetail.getOrigin() //and so on;
}
```

where FlightDetails is a class holding your various attributes:

```
class FlightDetails {
    private long departureTime;
    private String origin;
    //and so on, with various getters/setters
}
```

The for statement will print the items in the order they were inserted, since an ArrayList preserves that. Furthermore, you can also find out the 5th inserted element by simply doing a

```
flightDetails.get(5);
```

__

If you're looking for ordering based on insertion *as well as* access times (So that when you access a flight, it gets put to the top of the list), you can use a `LinkedHashMap`. [This link](http://javarticles.com/2012/06/linkedhashmap.html) talks in depth about it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to ask user and track or map sequence. Print the sequence as the list is sorted.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;

public class SequenceOfArray
{
    // Declare an ArrayList of Travel
    ArrayList<Travel>   travelList  = new ArrayList<Travel>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        SequenceOfArray s = new SequenceOfArray();
        s.addInput(0, 4); // add non sequentional input , so that sorting by departTime gives different sequenc
        s.addInput(10, 15);
        s.addInput(5, 9);

        s.travelList.sort(s.compareByDepartTime); // sort travel by departTime
        s.print();
        s.travelList.sort(s.compareById); // sort by id
        s.print();
    }

    public void print()
{
    System.out.println("id_______Leg______________Departure Time___________________________Origin_________Destination_____________Travel Time");
    for (int i = 0; i < travelList.size(); i++)
    {
        Travel t = travelList.get(i);
        // print travel, leg is dynamic, as your list is sorted.
        System.out.println(t.id + ".........." + i + ".................." + t.departTime + "........" + t.origin + "........." + t.destination + ".............." + t.departTime);
    }

}

    Comparator<Travel>  compareByDepartTime = new Comparator<Travel>()
                                            {

                                                @Override
                                                public int compare(Travel o1, Travel o2)
                                                {
                                                    return o1.departTime.compareTo(o2.departTime);
                                                }
                                            };
    Comparator<Travel>  compareById         = new Comparator<Travel>()
                                            {

                                                @Override
                                                public int compare(Travel o1, Travel o2)
                                                {
                                                    int i = 0;
                                                    if (o1.id - o2.id > 0)
                                                        return 1;
                                                    if (o1.id - o2.id < 0)
                                                        return -1;

                                                    return i;
                                                }
                                            };

    public void addInput(int start, int end)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            Travel t = new Travel();
            t.id = i;
            t.departTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            t.origin = "Origin" + (i + 1);
            t.destination = "Destination" + (i + 1);
            t.travelTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            travelList.add(t);
        }

    }

}

class Travel
{
    long    id;
    Date    departTime;
    String  origin;
    String  destination;
    Date    travelTime;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Sample output:

```
 id_______Leg______________Departure Time___________________________Origin_________Destination_____________Travel Time
0..........0..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin1.........Destination1..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
1..........1..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin2.........Destination2..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
2..........2..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin3.........Destination3..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
3..........3..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin4.........Destination4..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
10..........4..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin11.........Destination11..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
11..........5..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin12.........Destination12..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
12..........6..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin13.........Destination13..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
13..........7..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin14.........Destination14..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
14..........8..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin15.........Destination15..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
5..........9..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin6.........Destination6..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
6..........10..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin7.........Destination7..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
7..........11..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin8.........Destination8..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
8..........12..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin9.........Destination9..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
id_______Leg______________Departure Time___________________________Origin_________Destination_____________Travel Time
0..........0..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin1.........Destination1..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
1..........1..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin2.........Destination2..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
2..........2..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin3.........Destination3..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
3..........3..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin4.........Destination4..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
5..........4..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin6.........Destination6..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
6..........5..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin7.........Destination7..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
7..........6..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin8.........Destination8..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
8..........7..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin9.........Destination9..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
10..........8..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin11.........Destination11..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
11..........9..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin12.........Destination12..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
12..........10..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin13.........Destination13..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
13..........11..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin14.........Destination14..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
14..........12..................Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015........Origin15.........Destination15..............Sun Oct 04 05:11:51 GST 2015
```